# [SQL]One selected column and two values, select them in a row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqaak.png) :

With this select,

```
SELECT a.id, a.title, at.places, at.color FROM activityTypes as at inner join activitiesCombination as ac on at.id = ac.activityTypeId inner join activities as a on a.id = ac.activityId
```

I'm able to retrieve informations like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61unD.png) :

I would like to have all of these informations in this format :

id, title, color1, color2

Does you have the solution, knowing that many time there wont have two activity types for an activity ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have misunderstood your question you should use group_concat  and concat_ws functions

SELECT concat_ws(', ', a.id, a.title, at.places,group_concat( at.color)) FROM activityTypes as at inner join activitiesCombination as ac on at.id = ac.activityTypeId inner join activities as a on a.id = ac.activityId
Group by a.id, a.title, at.places

Answer (score 0):

Yoy should use concat_ws function. 
Write

SELECT concat_ws(', ', a.id, a.title, at.places, at.color)

Everything else should be the same.

Details arw in the manual
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws